# css: inside my fixed navigation, i cannot get the links to go beneath a spaceholder

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to revamp a site i once built:
www.Anke-Gerber.de

everything works okayish, unless you drag your browser window badly out of shape, or, unfortunately, use a mobile phone. 
Then, the liquid layout starts to overlap, the links overlap the logo.

To remedy this problem, I want to put a see-through placeholder png (called platzhalter.png in my code) on top of the Background Graphics, covering the logo.
If I managed to make the Link list go beneath that placeholder, it should stop overlapping the logo.

Unfortunately, within all the chaos of fixed and absolute positions (and i am somewhat sure that a lot of my position tags are completely superfluous, probably i need only one position:fixed, for the navigation div), i cannot find a way to make the links go beneath the placeholder.

I aprecciate any help!

my relevant html:

```
<div id="content">


<div id="text">
</div>


<div id="Navigation">   
    <div class="Logo">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/LogoHome2.png">

    </div>


    <div class="platzhalter">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/platzhalter.png">

    </div>
    <br>


  <div class="Link1"> 
     <a href="http://www.anke-gerber.de/wp/category/vita/"  onmousedown="if 
    (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()">
     <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/buttonVita1.png">  </a>
  </div>
```

and here is my relevant css:

```
#content{
    position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; 
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    Height: 100%;
    }

#Navigation{
    position: fixed; top: 0%; right: 0%; 
    z-index: 1;
    width: 43%;
    Height: 100%;
    Background-color:;
    }


.Logo img { 
    width: 100%;
    Position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    }


.platzhalter img {  
    width: 100%;
    Position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 4;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    }


.Link1 img {
    width: 13%;
    height: auto;
    Position: fixed; top: 39%; right: 8%; 
    z-index: 4;
    Background-color: ;
    }
```

I think that the problem lies within the position:fixed tags for the link, but when I remove that tag, the Link goes whereever.